# Is it okay to encrypt sqlite3 database with GnuPg?

Tags: sqlite, gnupg

I've been playing around with coding up a small password management command line utility in Python. Mostly just for fun, and probably nothing I would ever actually use since I already use established tools for this task.

The program stores site, user name, and password in a sqlite database, and provides various options for looking up passwords, accounts, etc. I was looking for a way to encrypt the sqlite database, because passwords, and I came across sqlcipher. I had trouble building it on mac os, and gave up on that pretty quickly. I decided to try just encrypting the database with GnuPg. From a usage stand point it seems to work well. I wrote a small wrapper in bash that quickly decrypts the database before any operation is done on it, and the re-encrypts it when its done. Is this an acceptable method for encrypting a sqlite database? I can't really find any other examples online of sqlite databases being encrypted this way.

Comment: How about just encrypting the data in each column?

Comment: I note that your approach would not be concurrency-safe: if two instances run at the same time then the file could be mangled.

Comment: The only person that can say something about whether this is acceptable or not is you. However, I would say this: G(nu)PG is not a in-flight encryption method, it is a system used for either long-term storage or transport of data. If you want a database that is both encrypted **and usable** as a database at the same time, then no, G(nu)PG is nowhere near the right solution for this. Instead you might want to look into [Sqlite Encryption Extension (SEE)](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki) which may or may not be available to you, or something built into your framework.

Comment: To **archive** a database, in a safe, encrypted, manner, then yes, G(nu)PG is one of your possible choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable method for encrypting a sqlite database?

If you consider it acceptable yes, others may or may not.

However, from a security point of view, probably not if you are decrypting the database file to use it and then encrypting it after use, as the decrypted version could be available and be accessed. The SEE ([SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki)) only decrypts to memory and then only partial data rather than the entire file, so would be more secure from the aspect of security.

> #### How SEE Works
>
> Each page is encrypted separately. The key to encryption
> is a combination of the page number, the random nonce (if any) and the
> database key. The data is encrypted in both the main database and in
> the rollback journal or WAL file but is unencrypted when held in
> memory. This means that if an adversary is able to view the memory
> used by your program, she will be able to see unencrypted data.

An alternative would be to store encrypted values, decrypting each as they are extracted, this would then equate to the decrypted value(s) only being in-memory. This could have the potential benefit of multiple key phrases (say for multiple users). Thus there would be no single key that unlocks all data.